# Finding Loop Iterator in static Analysis

Tags: c, loops, static-analysis

How can we find loop iterator in static analysis? What are different condition for a variable to be iterator?

In a super simplified for loop like `for(i = 0; i < n; i++);` we can assume that, lhs of initialization expression is iterator. But how can we find the iterator in a while loop or a more complex for loop?

I'm ready with following concepts:

- Reaching definitions
- Range Values
- Control flow graph

Comment: I'm afraid you can't even generally assume that "lhs of initialization expression is iterator". Plenty of `for` loops leave that part out completely, others have multiple declarations in there, yet others use a different iterator from the one initialized in there.

Comment: I don't think SO is designed for this question. A whole book could be (and probably has been) written on loop analysis.

Comment: @YePhIcK. I'm using that strategy for a super simple for loop. Question is also meant for other types of for loops as well.

Comment: Not sure what this question is about. It isn't even mandatory that a loop has an interator at all (and I mean all types of loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there is no *loop iterator*. For example, a single *iterator* variable may be insufficient (e.g., an array can be traversed from both ends simultaneously), termination of a loop can depend on external data (e.g., user input) and there are useful infinite loops (where iterators are useless).

However some heuristics can be used to identify *iterator* expressions. For loops they would frequently express two properties: **progress** and **termination**. Progress is often related to an update of the same variable with an value that depends on this variable, for example:

```
i++; // For indexed structures
p = p -> next; // For linked structures
```

Termination is often related to a comparison of a progress expression to some constant (meaning "constant for the loop"), for example:

```
i <= n; // For scalar values
p == null; // For pointers
```

In general there could be several progress expressions and therefore several termination constants, and several progress variables can be used in a termination expression.

So, a basic strategy would be:

1. Collect all variables from an exit condition of a loop.
2. Check which of them are modified in a loop body with a dependency on themselves.

But keep in mind, that some loops have no progress expressions, some have no termination conditions, variable updates can be indirect and there is aliasing.

Comment: This answer seems to be fair. At least a good start. Thanks. I'm closing this question for time being.